# Recognize logged WP user in existing REST API

Tags: users, rest-api, session

I have a plugin using *pre_get_post* filter to hide posts depending on which user is logged. However the "parent page" selector in the WP "edit post" page uses a wp-json call to get existing pages.

This creates a big problem: logged user is not recognized and restricted posts are always hidden.

Is there a way to hook into those REST API calls (eg. *wp-json/wp/v2/pages?context=edit*) and pass the user nonce or any way to recognize the user?

I read a lot about the X-WP-Nonce parameter, but I'm not creating a new REST call. I need to hook in existing ones.

Answer (score -1):

You can recognize a user by passing user-id

Example:

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?author=1
```

This author parameter will recognize author posts and return those

Comment: This is not what I asked though. I need to recognize it into **existing** calls (eg. the one used by WordPress to search for parent pages in the "edit page" screen)